# Find out if any tables have been updated in your database with new data

Tags: mysql

**MySQL**

mysqladmin  Ver 8.42 Distrib 5.6.25-73.1, for Linux on x86_64

Is there a (i'm sure there is) cmd in ssh (putty) that allows you to search the whole db for any new insertions or updates to data. If any user including myself. I guess similar to the way version control works where it shows commits.

Comment: We need more information

Comment: Sorry, i know that was kind of short but i'm not really sure what else to say...  If any user including myself has updated any table is there a way to find out what table and the date it was updated?

Comment: I guess similar to the way version control works where it shows commits. @Ramhound

Comment: You have not even told us what database your using.  Your current question is unanswerable without know that

Comment: mysql DB and Percona Server @Ramhound

Comment: This is totally dependent on the database layout. It also has absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with PuTTY, or SSH, and likely not even the shell. I'm also tempted to say that it is off topic as a programming question, but IMO the more pressing matter is that it's unanswerable without knowing the database layout.

Comment: Is there a way i can easily access and show the DB layout? @MichaelKjörling

Comment: I think @supplement should clarify whether he's looking for a generic solution. If that's the case, I think the question is valid as it has nothing to do with the schema/layout. There's a similar one for SQL Server, and some approaches exist: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489469/find-the-last-time-table-was-updated

Comment: exactly, just a generic solution, that thread above helps.